# Theme twig files front page is empty

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to build a custom theme in drupal.
I have two page files:

```
page.html.twig
page--front.html.twig
```

both files have the same code:

```
<div class="container">
    {{ page.myheader }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{ page.sitebrand }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
```

The Problem:
I see the blocks in all the pages except the front page.

by the way: 
I did set my front page as this:
[image]
I created a simple page with 'front' alias.

Is this cousing a problem?

The question: 
What am I doing wrong? 
How can make different display in the front page?

full `page--front.html.twig`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    {{ page.myheader }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{ page.sitebrand }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

xxx dagfv

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">
                Default
            </button>
            <div class="btn-group">

                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    Action
                </button>
                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="disabled">
                        <a href="#">Another action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                {{ page.mainmenu }}
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ page.content }}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you paste the complete `page--front.html.twig`? Did you see the blocks before creating the separate `page--front.html.twig`?

Comment: added the full `page--front.html.twig` code in the question above. I made some tests and i know that the site reads the the front.twig file. I just dont understand why the blocks are not showing. Does it have anything to do the the naming of the blocks placeholders in the file? maybe I an doing something wrong calling the front page in the configuration area.

Comment: Try giving your node a different path, for example "frontpage" and keep the `page--front.html.twig` as-is.

Comment: Created a new page called `/frontpage`. I entered the page and I see the blocks. I've replaced the front page in configuration->basic site settings so now the `/frontpage` is the index. entered the main page. don't see any blocks...

Comment: Clear cache to allow Drupal to register the new theme file

Comment: I have cleared the cache, no changes... still no blocks.

Comment: Where have you located tourneys twig files in your custom theme?

Comment: What are the tourneys twig files? you mean the twig files? thy are located in the theme base folder.  `/var/www/html/ac8/themes/achva_theme/page.html.twig`

Comment: If you delete page--front.html.twig and clear the cache, can you see the blocks in the front page?

Comment: I have deleted the `page--front.html.twig` file, cleared the cache and i do not see the blocks. **note**: I placed a string in the  `page--front.html.twig` file So I will know if the Drupal reads the front file and it did, the string apeard only in the front page. What can be the problem?

Comment: what i see is the data of the `/frontpage` page (when it was published and by who).

Comment: Best to locate you twig files in a sub-folder named templates `/themes/achva_theme/templates/`

Comment: Thank you, I i did it. but I still don't see the blocks on the front page...

Comment: So it seems is not the twig file fault. Check your blocks configuration. See if for visibility they have exclude front page.

Comment: Way too much at this point... should be in chat.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problem.

1. page--front.html.twig is special suggestion template for front page. Any url set to front page always use this template => You don't need set alias for this.Just set page you want to front page.
2. Don't add html tag to page template. The tree of template is html=>page=>region=>block... Html tag exited in template html.html.twig.

And more you can setting [twig debug](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-compiled-twig-templates) to see current home page use template?